# Wavlink is not working on the Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS - USB-C to HDMI Dual Display Adapter

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, hdmi, displaylink

I am trying to use two monitors on Ubuntu 20.04.4 with the [wavlink UG7602HC
USB3.0/USB-C to HDMI Dual Display Adapter (Model: WL-UG7602HC)](https://www.wavlink.com/en_us/product/WL-UG7602HC.html):

```
$ uname -a
Linux 5.13.0-27-generic Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

CPU: Intel i5-7400 (4) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630
```

I install the DisplayLink software on Ubuntu 20.04 ([as described here](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0)) the download from [DisplayLink support for Ubuntu now available](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683482-displaylink-support-for-ubuntu-now-available)

```
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
WARNING: Version 1.10.1 of EVDI kernel module is already running.
```

The device is already connected to the system:

```
$ lsusb                         
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 090c:0768 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) SMI USB Display
```

When I try to connect the two monitors, Nothing happens.

The two monitors, have the following resolutions:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

For some reason, the computer does not detect the monitors.

Someone has some idea how to fix this?

Any suggestion is welcome :)

Thank you!

Comment: $ Linux 5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already did what you describe above.

Comment: This is a big problem! Problem not solve yet :( wavlink display is so expensive! This is  bad.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the Latest Official Driver from https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu. It was a zip file containing two files, the first being instructions and the second being:

```
$ file displaylink-driver-5.7.0-61.129.run 
displaylink-driver-5.7.0-61.129.run: POSIX shell script executable (binary data)
```

After `chmod 700` on that .run file and running it, it installed some packages and asked me to create a password. It then rebooted and asked me for that same password. The two monitors (plus my laptop) started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was able to solve it in the following way:

- disable Secure Boot in UEFI
- uninstall DisplayLink driver -> `sudo displaylink-installer --uninstall`
- Install the driver again (downloaded from the official display page)
- restart computer

Comment: There's no need to uninstall/reinstall, that's an unfortunate symptom of "Windows mentality".

Comment: Although you do not believe it. it was necessary to do the process with a windows mentality. without uninstalling the driver the monitor was not detected and when I reinstalled it it worked